Applications of Electrostatics in Computer Engineering
I am currently studying Computer Engineering and am enrolled in a Physics 2 class. For an upcoming presentation, my teacher has asked us to explore and present the applications of electrostatic physics within our field.
I am particularly interested in demonstrating how concepts such as Coulomb's Law and Gauss's Law are relevant to computer engineering. However, I am struggling to find concrete examples that effectively illustrate these principles in practice.
Ideally, I would like to focus on applications related to software engineering, but I am open to exploring concepts in electronics as well. For instance, I am considering discussing how to prevent electrostatic discharge (ESD) in circuits or how Coulomb's Law can be applied in circuit design.
Could you please provide guidance on specific topics or examples that I could research and develop for my presentation? Any suggestions on how to effectively connect these electrostatic principles to real-world applications in computer engineering would be greatly appreciated.

The design of semiconductor devices, such as PN junctions, makes heavy use of electrostatics. In particular, the Poisson equation is relevant. This might be a bit above what you've been taught in class, but the Poisson equation is essentially a combination of Gauss' law for electric flux, plus the concept of electrostatic potential.

It may not apply to your field. Think of an English major who is taking the class to satisfy general education requirements. His answer might be that studying electrostatics puts me to sleep. This ensures I am well rested and do well in my English classes.

You might want to look at the operating principle of the MOSFET. Without the MOSFET, the hardware running your software would be dramatically more power-hungry.

The question is probably off-topic in this community, but since the following constitutes technically an answer, I post it as such.
Firstly, I doubt that electrostatics (and physics in general) is relevant to software engineering (beyond perhaps inspiring some algorithms), since physics deals with material world - i.e., the hardware.
Hardware is obviously electronic circuits, with charges running in them carrying signal - so learning a bit about how a computer chip works, more precisely learning about transistors, resistances and other basic elements of electronic devices is the way to go. Despite being packaged in smaller in smaller volumes, these are conceptually no different from the transistor electronics of the second half of the XX-th century. There are plenty of books like Physics of semiconductor devices, adapted to all levels of knwoledge.
More fancy subjects may include modern nanostructures, using effects like Coulomb blockade, plasma resonances, etc. But this is better tackled, when one is comfortable with the basics.
Remark
From how the Q. is formulated, I suspect that looking into hardware pushes the OP a bit out of their comfort zone - but I also suspect this is precisely the teacher's intention. Thus getting a bit of hardware background is the way towards a good grade, even if the subject does not inspire you.

The most likely application would be for you to write software that somehow uses electrostatics. Perhaps given a charge distribution, it calculates and displays the fields. See these optical puzzles for an excellent example fron 3blue1brown. Of course, this software might well be used to display other things. E.G. see How I animate 3Blue1Brown | A Manim demo with Ben Sparks
More likely, you would need electrostatic to solve some technical problem. It might be more general than a static case. For example, designing a wave guide or an antenna.
If you are a professional programmer, the kinds of problem you work on will depend on the company you work for and the industry it serves. For example, there are vastly complex and challenging business applications that, say, keep track of insurance accounts. You are less likely to use physics of any sort in that kind of job than if you work for a technical company.
